# Please correct me for this '人多就是非多'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm a bit confused with '非' here.

Does it mean:

1.'not': which the sentence then would mean the numbers of people wouldn't change anything

2.'mistake': 'a lot of people = A lot of mistakes'

or, from the example I found:

'过节人多，人多就是非多，请问各地警力有保障吗？愿大家都高高兴兴出门，平平安安回家！'

3. Either 'trash' or 'criminal'?

Comment: Maybe, it's more understandable and natural to say 人多 就是 是非 多。or 人多 是非就(是)多。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [是非](http://www.zdic.net/c/f/14b/326880.htm) should be interpreted as an unbroken word here, it means

> (2) [discord]∶口舌;纠纷

So "人多就是非多" should be interpreted as

```
人多 (when/if) there're many people
就 then
是非 discord (would be)
多 much
```

Comment: That makes much more sense, I was reading it as 人多-就是-非多...

Comment: @Fai91 Yes this is confusing because "就是" is a commonly used word too.